# How to check if a given number is a factorial or not in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

For example 24, is a factorial because:

```
 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
```

The code should take 24 as an input and the output (see below) should be if it is a factorial or not.

```
    return "is a factorial."
else:
    return "is not a factorial."
print("The number " + str(24) + " " + str(isFactorial(24)))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to have it backwards. Generate factorials until you find it or not. That way, you are sure always to compare integers:

```
def is_factorial(n):
    i = f = 1
    while f < n:
        i += 1
        f *= i
    return f == n
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose you 2 solutions:

```
def check_fact(n):
    i = fact = 1
    while fact<n:
        i += 1
        fact *= i
    return fact==n

def check_fact_opt(n):
    i = 1
    while n>1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n /= i
        else:
            break
        i+=1
    return n<=1
```

Both solve produce the same result and both solve your problem, but the latter is much less iterations:

```
        N          is_fact     n_it  is_fact_opt  n_it_opt
2               |   True    |   1   |   True    |   1   
6               |   True    |   2   |   True    |   2   
24              |   True    |   3   |   True    |   3   
50              |   False   |   4   |   False   |   2   
100             |   False   |   4   |   False   |   2   
120             |   True    |   4   |   True    |   4   
200             |   False   |   5   |   False   |   2   
500             |   False   |   5   |   False   |   2   
1000            |   False   |   6   |   False   |   2   
5040            |   True    |   6   |   True    |   6   
100000          |   False   |   8   |   False   |   2   
3628800         |   True    |   9   |   True    |   9   
3628801         |   False   |   10  |   False   |   1   
100000000000    |   False   |   14  |   False   |   2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a ready made list of large amount of factorial numbers sorted in an array like this

```
 List: 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, ...
```

Then search through this list to see if your number is valid or not
I suggest to use binary search, since the list is sorted.

> List of factorial numbers [Link](http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/fact.html)

Answer (score -2):

(untested and written in a hurry)

```
def isfac(n):
    i = 2
    while n > 1:
        n = n / i
        i = i + 1
    return n == 1
```

Comment: @CalebGoodman Which this post isn't answering. It does however, compare `float` objects for exact equality.